# HighCharts set scrollbar position

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I have implemented Highcharts for my project.Time showing in x-Axis and speed in y-Axis.

I needs to start recent Time in x-Axis.When I loading the chart I need to scroll it on horizontal direction towards the right to get the recent time.

```
        ....
        xAxis: {
        reversed:true,
        align: "left",
        type: 'datetime',
        title: {
                text: 'Time'
            },
        min:sorted_data[0][0],
        max:sorted_data[sorted_data.length-1][0] - 36000000
    } ...
```

I created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kiranlm/qdvca1vt/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not setting min and max like this:

```
max:sorted_data[sorted_data.length-1][0],
min:sorted_data[sorted_data.length-1][0] - 36000000
```

Or something similar? I mean, simply set `min` and `max`, where max is the last item and min is the beginning of the scrollbar.

Comment: Please try in fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kiranlm/qdvca1vt/2 , Its not working in fiddle

Comment: Ah, small mistake in the answer, swap min<->max values, working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qdvca1vt/3/

Comment: When i inverts the x-axis, scrollbar is not inverts along with it. that's the actual problem i could not find any solution in highcharts documentation.

Comment: Oh, you refer that bug! See [this list](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/search?q=reversed&state=open&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93).